# How to get value from item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

How to get value from `RecyclerView` item and pass it to `EditText`. This part of code below shows my project name when click on item

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        edit.setText("text" + adapter.getItem(position));
        edit.setText(toString().toUpperCase());

    }
```

Comment: edit.setText("text" + adapter.getItem(position).toString().toUpperCase()); change your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go over it

```
edit.setText("text" + adapter.getItem(position));
```

Line above sets text of for (I assume) `EditText`. The text that is set is an item cast to string at `position`

```
edit.setText(toString().toUpperCase());
```

This line sets text for the exact same object, but this time it sets it from `toString()` method. It is important to know in such case which `toString()` is called. In this instance - it's from the Adapter - the class in which you redefined `onItemClick`

To get what you wanted to do would be to change it to:

```
edit.setText(
    "text" +
    adapter
        .getItem(position)
        .toString()
        .toUpperCase()
)
```

You can collapse it into one line - I did it that way to help illustrate what's going on.

That way `toString()` method that is called is not from the whichever class you happen to write it in, but for that exact object you got from `getItem()`

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :) You can mark my answer if it helped with your problem